# Styling MarkerClusterer Icons?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am using the MarkerCluster.js to create clustering in my google maps api. The clusters work how I want them however I want to style differently than yellow, blue and red circles. I was trying to use the MarkerStyleOptions and it says you have an array of styles with the smallest cluster icon first and the biggest last. I tried to create this below but I am getting really confused about what syntax to use and can't find any good examples.

```
var clusterStyles = [
    [opt_textColor: 'white'],
    [opt_textColor: 'white'],
    [opt_textColor: 'white']
];

var mcOptions = {
    gridSize: 50,
    styles: clusterStyles,
    maxZoom: 15
};
var markerclusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, cluster, mcOptions);
```

Comment: this is totally wrong, even the syntax of the arrays inside the variable

Answer (score 103, accepted):

What you need to do is use the url to specify which images to use instead of the blue/yellow/red images currently being used.  And probably a good idea to include the height and width options too.

```
var clusterStyles = [
  {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'path/to/smallclusterimage.png',
    height: 50,
    width: 50
  },
 {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'path/to/mediumclusterimage.png',
    height: 50,
    width: 50
  },
 {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'path/to/largeclusterimage.png',
    height: 50,
    width: 50
  }
];
```

Comment: Hi Thankyou, :) Yes I used this and it worked really well, I knew I was just getting the way you write the array wrong. One more thing is there any way of having html markup of say a <div> box with a h2 and p tag, instead of a static image?

Comment: Duncan, do you know if it is possible to use an icon instead of an image url? I mean an icon constructed with google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, filColor etc.

Comment: According to [the comments in the JS file here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0.2/src/markerclusterer.js) that isn't possible, it just expects a URL

Comment: It's textColor, not opt_textColor.

Comment: If you want to create simple icons more dynamic and performant way, check this question about using svg for marker cluster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178080/getting-google-map-markerclusterer-plus-icons-in-one-color/37302915#37302915

Comment: Sorry for being late comer. Why do you have 3 clusterer. When u zoom out more it becomes medium and large right?

Comment: @Emre yes exactly. Look at the example here, and change the Cluster Style and look at their JS to see how they've done it: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html

Answer (score 5):

It's never too late to post a rather helpful answer, so additionally you can look through the whole [MarkerClusterer Documentation for IconStyle](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html)

**UPDATE**

There's also [google maps v3 utility on github](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library) as stated by ehcanadian

Comment: This is MarkerClustererPlus, my understanding is that it's different than MarkerClusterer v3?

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: Thats why Link only answer is not useful.

Comment: The repo was moved to https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer and it doesn't appear IconStyle made the transition.

Comment: Link to docs on web.archive.org. Hopefully this will be available permanently http://web.archive.org/web/20160122183325/http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

Comment: There's a repo for this here: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus

Answer (score 3):

According to [latest docs](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer), renderer does the trick.  It allows you to use a Marker w/all its styling options - see [Marker documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple):

```
     new MarkerClusterer({
      renderer: {
        render: ({ markers, _position: position }) => {

          //here is where you return a Marker
          //and style it w/custom label/icon props
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
              lat: position.lat(),
              lng: position.lng(),
            },
            label: String(markers.length),
          });
        },
      },
      ...etc
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can now pass your own renderer to your MarkerClusterer Object which returns a google.maps.Marker like this:

```
const renderer = {
    render({ count, position }) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            label: { text: String(count), color: "white", fontSize: "10px" },
            position,
            // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
            zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
        });
    }
}

// use this if you use NPM version
const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, renderer });

// Use this if you use the CDN version
// const markerCluster = new  markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map , renderer});
```

Inside the render method, you can customize the cluster maker the same way you would customize normal marker. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers for more details. For example, if you just want to add a specific icon.png you could do it like this:

```
const icon = {
            url: '/path/to/your/icon.png',
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
};

const renderer = {
                render({ count, position }) {
                    return new google.maps.Marker({
                        label: { text: String(count), color: "white", fontSize: "10px" },
                        position,
                        icon,
                        // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
                        zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
                    });
                }
            }
```

You can also find some clustor marker render example at https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/public/renderers/

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering for a full example how to setup MarkerCluster.

---

**History Details:**

The MarkerCluster library has been rewritten in 2021. One goal was to change the render process. The cluster icon itself is now a google.maps.Marker and can thus be styled just as normal marker. The `mcOptions` in the constructor is gone.

> The proposed design is to encapsulate the logic for clustering and rendering into interfaces that the developer can extend specifically algorithm and renderer. The algorithm computes the clusters and the renderer generates a google.maps.Marker to represent clusters instead of using a google.maps.OverlayView.

- https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus/issues/300
- https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus/issues/293
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1X8hQaHdVvpB-12bOQ_qbgfGFet8gPRTtHyO_EihcpsA/edit

Answer (score 0):

Adam, please correct your code: `const renderer = { render: ({ count, position }) => new Marker ...`

The following works fine:

```js
const renderer = {
   render: ({ count, position }) =>
     new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: { url:"path_to_image_file" }, 
        label: { text: String(count), color: "white", fontSize: "10px" },
        position,
        // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
        zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
   }),
};

new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
  map,
  markers,
  renderer,
});
```